# Is there a way to match in Mockito by reference and equals at the same time?

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito

Mockito's `Matchers` has `eq()` which uses `equals` and `same()` which uses `==` operator.

Is there a way to use both when comparing objects in `Mockito`?

Let's say we have

```
List list1 = new ArrayList();
List list2 = new ArrayList();

System.out.println(list1.equals(list2));  //true
System.out.println(list1 == list2);       //false

/* and I want to check that the references are the same, 
   and the list contents haven't changed */
```

so it would be great to have a operator that does both checking by `==` and `.equals()`

> 

This would come in handy if you want to check that the return is the same list, and the list contents are the same without doing 2 assertions.

Also, this may be a classic example of the 4 card problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wason_selection_task

`.equals()` can be true even if objects don't have the same reference.

So `.equals()` being true doesn't mean `==` would return true and is not a substitute.

Comment: How would you *want* it to use both? It's not clear what effect you're trying to achieve. As an aside, any `equals` implementation which doesn't return `true` when `==` *does* yield true is broken.

Comment: For a List, equals compares objects, and == compares the references. If I want to match the same list, with the same objects this would help.

Comment: But surely `equals` just works in that case. It would be *much* easier to understand your question if you'd give a short but complete example. You've given *bits* of an example now, but it's still far from clear. Full code you want to test, plus the test itself, ideally avoiding raw types, would make it much easier to help you.

Comment: You can't use them in the same test since they are not mutually exclusive, Mockito will take the last rule that is nearest fit.

Comment: Upvoted for doing your research on `eq()` and `same()`, which helped me learn about the latter.

Answer (score 1):

The `equals` implementation should do a `==` check. If it doesn´t I would expect this as a bug. So doing both is not necessary. If you let eclipse generate `equals` the first test is a `==` check for example.

The same applies for a List, this is the `equals` of `AbstractList`:

```
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    if (o == this)
        return true;
    if (!(o instanceof List))
        return false;

    ListIterator<E> e1 = listIterator();
    ListIterator e2 = ((List) o).listIterator();
    while (e1.hasNext() && e2.hasNext()) {
        E o1 = e1.next();
        Object o2 = e2.next();
        if (!(o1==null ? o2==null : o1.equals(o2)))
            return false;
    }
    return !(e1.hasNext() || e2.hasNext());
}
```

Comment: can't do 2 assertions when using doNothing().when(variable).method(list1);

Comment: Doing `==` in an `equals` isn't a "should do": `a.equals(a)` just **must** return `true` (reflexivity). How it comes to that conclusion is up to the developer.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to succeed without any configuration. Here is the code:

```
public class MockedObject {
    public String foo(List list) {
        throw new RuntimeException("foo");
    }
}

public class User {
   public void boo(MockedObject object, List list1) {
       System.out.println(object.foo(new ArrayList()));
   }
}

@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class UserTest {
    @Mock
    MockedObject mockedObject;

    @Test
    public void testUser() throws Exception {
        List list1 = new ArrayList();
        List list2 = new ArrayList();
        when(mockedObject.foo(list1)).thenReturn("mocked");
        User user = new User();
        user.boo(mockedObject, list1);

        user.boo(mockedObject, list2);
    }
}
```

Test is passed, output is:

```
mocked
mocked
```